# worksheetfunction.aggregate ignore hidden/error/0 values

Tags: vba, excel

this code works until the loops encounter a blank/error cell value

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wstest As Worksheet, wskb As Worksheet
Dim lastrowinc As Long, curRow As Long, lastrowkb As Long
Dim medianvalue As Integer
Dim critvalue As String


'Sheet to look up Critvalue
Set ws1 = Sheets("Incident")

'Sheet where to store Medianvalue
Set wstest = Sheets("Sheet3")

'Sheet where to get Critvalue (A2 onwards)
Set wskb = Sheets("KB Articles")

'For autofilter criteria
lastrowinc = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


lastrowkb = wskb.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For curRow = 2 To lastrowkb

critvalue = wskb.Range("A" & curRow).Value

ws1.Range("M1:A" & lastrowinc).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=critvalue



medianvalue = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, Columns(2))


wstest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = medianvalue


Next curRow
```

now according to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195373.aspx) we can use 7 as Arg2 to ignore hidden and error. I tried but it still gives an error 1004 on this line: `medianvalue = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, Columns(2))`

(note i tried 5 and 7 but still the same error). i even tried to set all blank cells to cause an excel error (#N/A) but to no avail. it works until it meets a BLANK/error cell

i also have a question with the result output. why is it displaying a whole number? I had this working with on a manual autofilter criteria before (with a texbox) and it displays a value with decimals but when i looped it up it a whole number.

thanks guys.

Comment: can you add a sample of your data? i'm trying to recreate your issue.

Comment: You declared your variable as an Integer, which is a whole number...

Comment: As @Rory said, changed `Dim medianvalue As Integer` to `Dim medianvalue As Double`

Comment: yep thanks for that guys. i'm able to fix the integer issue. instead of assigning it to a variable i just went ahead and throw the value into a cell without any data types.

Comment: on with the primary issue, i need a way to move the "curRow" value if it cannot search "critValue" in "incident". i've tried to intercept it by using : If Not wskb.Range("A" & curRow).Find(ws1.Range("M" & curRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then


curRow = curRow + 1


End If but apparently it did not work.  i need a way to push the curRow to the next row if it cannot find the critValue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the existence of at least one numberic value using the `Count` function.

```
If WorksheetFunction.Count(ws1.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) > 0 Then
    medianvalue = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, ws1.Columns(2))
Else
    medianvalue = some value that is meaningful to you
End If
```

Comment: i think i know what my issue now is please help. so the criteriavalue can always be found in ws1 but after the autofilter there will be a column in ws1 where it will have a blank cell (Column B). `WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, ws1.Columns(2))` errors out when it encounters a collection of cell with a blank column. any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: The code I posted should let you handle that. You need to decide what value you want reported when the column is blank.